# PHP Reflection create class instance (object) with an array of arguments passed to the constructor

Tags: php, class, reflection, constructor, instantiation

How to instantiate class Bar with PHP Reflection?

class code:

```
class Bar
{
    private $one;
    private $two;

    public function __construct($one, $two) 
    {
        $this->one = $one;
        $this->two = $two;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return ($this->one + $this->two);
    }
}
```

I ran out of ideas, some of my guesswork is:

```
$class = 'Bar';
$constructorArgumentArr = [2,3];
$reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($class,'__construct');
$object = $reflectionMethod->invokeArgs($class, $constructorArgumentArr);

echo $object->get(); //should echo 5
```

but this will not work since invokeArgs() requires an object not a class name so I have a chicken-egg case: I don't have an object so I cannot use constructor method and I need to use constructor method to get the object.

I tried to pass null as `$class` as the first argument following the logic that constructor is called at the time when there's no object yet but I got: "ReflectionException: Trying to invoke non static method ..."

If there is no solution available by Reflection I'll accept any other (ie php function).

References:
[Reflection Method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php)
[ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.reflectionclass.php) and [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

```
    class Bar
    {
        private $one;
        private $two;

        public function __construct($one, $two) 
        {
            $this->one = $one;
            $this->two = $two;
        }

        public function get()
        {
            return ($this->one + $this->two);
        }
    }

    $args = [2, 3];
    $reflect  = new \ReflectionClass("Bar");
    $instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
    echo $instance->get();
```